# Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name ( django-rest-framework )

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

## Problem :

I am getting an error like this .

> ImproperlyConfigured at /api/users/
>
> Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name
>   "user-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in
>   your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on
>   this field.

I read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20550598/django-rest-framework-could-not-resolve-url-for-hyperlinked-relationship-using) but it didn't work.

### serializers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='user-detail',
                                               lookup_field='profile')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'url')


class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user.username')

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = "__all__"
        # user = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        pass

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        pass
```

### urls.py

```
user_profile_list = UserProfileViewSet.as_view({
    'get': 'list',
    'post': 'create'
})
user_profile_detail = UserProfileViewSet.as_view({
    'get': 'retrieve',
    'put': 'update',
    'patch': 'partial_update',
    'delete': 'destroy'
})
user_list = UserViewSet.as_view({
    'get': 'list'
})
user_detail = UserViewSet.as_view({
    'get': 'retrieve'
})
user_profiles_detail = UserViewSet.as_view({
    'get': 'profile'
})

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'userprofiles', views.UserProfileViewSet)
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls))
]
```

### views.py

```
class UserProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    This viewset automatically provides `list`, `create`, `retrieve`,
    `update` and `destroy` actions.
    """
    queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
                          IsOwnerOrReadOnly,)
    pagination_class = LimitTenPagination

    @detail_route(renderer_classes=[renderers.JSONRenderer])
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    """
    This viewset automatically provides `list` and `detail` actions
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

### Snippet from my models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
```

#### What I tried :

I tried changing `user-detail` to `api:user-detail` ( yes `api` namespace do exist in the main **urls.py** file )

Comment: I understand that what you want is to have a field in the `User` serializer pointing to the URL of its profile, right?

Comment: Are you trying to have url point to the user detail view or the user profile detail view?

Comment: @JessamynSmith I am trying to get it to user-detail, that's why I have chosen the `model` as `User` and not `UserProfile`

Comment: @dukebody yes, that's it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Looking at the docs, I believe you have to use `HyperLinkedRelatedField`. Also, see [this related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31566675/for-django-rest-framework-what-is-the-difference-in-use-case-for-hyperlinkedrel).
2. You are confusing arguments in your serializer field definition. What I believe should be:

   ```
   class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
       url = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(view_name='api:userprofile-detail',
                                                 source='profile')
   ```

## Edit :

Added `namespace` **api**

Comment: I found that this worked only if I named the field the same as in the model, e.g.: profile = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(read_only=True, view_name='userprofiles-detail')

Comment: @JessamynSmith yes that's why namespace needs to be added

Answer (score 1):

Remove `lookup_filed` attribute from your `HyperlinkedIdentityField` since you do not need it.

Hence your `serializer` class should instead look like below:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='user-detail', source='profile',)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'url')
```

The attribute `lookup_filed` is only needed when referring to a model class with `relationship-field/attribute` used as a **primary key** instead of the default `autoincrement`. For example, it would have been relevant to use it if your model class looked like below:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile', primary_key=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're extending the GenericViewSet and ListModelMixin classes, and have the same error when adding the url field in the list view, it's because you're not defining the detail view. Be sure you're extending the RetrieveModelMixin mixin:

```
class UserViewSet (mixins.ListModelMixin,
                   mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                   viewsets.GenericViewSet):
```

Credits to an answer from Rowinson Gallego